# Applying style to Autosuggest box crashes the App: Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'FormsCustomizableTextBox' to an object of type 'TextBox'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have recently started developing an UWP application.

I have defined a style in my page resources like this:

```
<Style TargetType="AutoSuggestBox" x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiLight"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5"/>
            <Setter Property="PlaceholderText" Value="Type Here"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
</Style>
```

Then I am using this style in the same page like:

```
<AutoSuggestBox Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}"
                Name="SchemeSuggestBox"
                QuerySubmitted="SchemeSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
                SuggestionChosen="SchemeSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"
                TextChanged="SchemeSuggestBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Doing this however crashes the app with exception:

```
Exception = {"No installed components were detected. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800F1000)"}
```

And message:

```
Message = "Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.FormsCustomizableTextBox' to an object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox'."
```

If I remove the style from my AutoSuggestBox (The following line) the App works as expected:

```
Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}"
```

What gives? I am not applying this style to any TextBox at all.

I have already read the [Official Docs on Autosuggest box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AutoSuggestBox) (<s>Turns out it isn't even inherited from TextBox class</s> It does have a property as Siva Gopal described and BugFinder hinted. Apparently I was kind of an idiot to miss it).

Relevant discussion on Xamarin forum can be seen [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38565/xf-for-windows-phone-8-1-early-preview-problems-with-changing-styles-at-runtime).

Comment: Surely part of the auto suggest is a text box?

Comment: @BugFinder Presumably (It kinda looks like it so must be inherited from it?). I can't be sure as I have just started dabbling with it. Reading the Docs on Autosuggestbox rn.

Comment: @NSNoob Did you cross check if there is no other style with same name exist somewhere else in the application resources? Did you try changing the style name to something like: MyAutoSuggestBoxStyle ?

Comment: @SivaGopal Yes I have checked the resource dictionary in App.Xaml and also tried changing the style name to "Random2681938" to make sure. Results are the same. Let me know if You'd like to inspect the resource dictionaries yourself

Comment: @NSNoob I think your style's `TargetType` should be `TextBox` and need to apply it for `TextBoxStyle`: `<AutoSuggestBox TextBoxStyle={StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}/>`. Give it a try.

Comment: @SivaGopal That's it. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: @NSNoob Sure, provided it as answer, tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your style's `TargetType` should be: `TextBox` but not: `AutoSuggestBox` and need to apply it for `TextBoxStyle` on AutoSuggestBox:

**Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxStyle">
   ...
</Style>
```

**Style Application:**

```
<AutoSuggestBox TextBoxStyle={StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}>
   ...
</AutoSuggestBox>
```